# MYSQL Query to get invoice items from invoice table using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. I want to extract data from two tables `tbl_invoice` and `tbl_invoices_details`.

First table
[image: Invoice Table]

Second Hand
[image: Invoice Details Table]

I have tried but it's not working.

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM tbl_invoice 
INNER JOIN tbl_invoice_details 
        ON tbl_invoice.invoice_id=tbl_invoice_details.invoice_id   
     WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_id="4"
     GROUP by department_name
```

Alternatively, I have a query that gets all the invoices for a particular department in a particular month.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_invoice 
 WHERE department_name="DIFA" 
   AND order_date BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-10-13'
```

but not sure how to get the individual items as list in those invoices.

Comment: what is the desired result ? can you share create and insert statements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of group by :

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n,   
aggregate_function (expression)  
FROM tables  
[WHERE conditions]  
GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n;
```

TO learn more . Please visit [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-group-by)

For your case :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_invoice INNER JOIN tbl_invoice_details ON tbl_invoice.invoice_id=tbl_invoice_details.invoice_id WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_id="4" GROUP by department_name
```

Here (*) of your select statement needs to be replaced with **department_name** and your desired **aggragate_functions (example -  count,sum etc)**. And separated by comma.

If you just want to join then remove **GROUP BY** .
Fetch the result **tbl_invoice.field_name** or **tbl_invoice_details.field_name**.

It should work this way.

Comment: Using the `SELECT department_name , SUM(total) FROM `tbl_invoice` INNER JOIN tbl_invoice_details ON tbl_invoice.invoice_id=tbl_invoice_details.invoice_id` i can get the total however i need the list of the products that make that total.

Comment: sorry i have corrected ny script above to get the list of products. Thank you